# How to set BLOB Data in SQLite to Nothing or NULL

Tags: sqlite

How to SET BLOB data field in a SQL Table to NULL or Nothing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in every other database too. If the column allows nulls.

INSERT INTO test1 (blob_col) values (null);

or

UPDATE test1 set blob_col = null;

Comment: Forgot about the NULL keyword :(   I was trying it like `UPDATE test1 set blob_col = '';`